# BeautifulSoup: using strings to get a value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to use a string to get a value of a tag?

XML structure:

```
book
   title
      titletext
book
   title
      titletext
```

Code:

```
books = BeautifulStoneSoup().findAll('book')
for book in books:
    book.title.titletext.string
    #book.get_by_string('title.titletext').string is this possible?
```

If it's not possible does getattr support multiple levels?

```
getattr(book, 'title.titletext').string
```

I did some testing and this doesn't seem to be possible but maybe there is an alternative?

If there isn't I guess I have to write my own recursive function to find the attribute?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use lxml.html? Its just better for this sort of thing.

Comment: `getattr` doesn't support multiple levels, although it would be easy enough to write a little function to split on `.` and call getattr several times. But there's probably a simpler way to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jakob I need a pure Python solution @Thomas Yep, that's what I am doing now but I also thought there should be something better.

Comment: Have you considered standard library solutions, like ElementTree?

Comment: @Thomas I took a quick look at ElementTree and it might have what I need. The find method allows a path to a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into ElementTree.  It has what you need.  As a quick example:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree

doc = xml.etree.cElementTree.parse( filename )
for e in doc.getiterator( 'title' ):
    book_title = e.attrib[ 'titletext' ]
```

Obviously I'm not handling error conditions, but using try/except or checking to see if 'titletext' is in the dict is sufficient.

If you are looking for a specific tag, and not an attribute of the tag, the above code will still work:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree

doc = xml.etree.cElementTree.parse( filename )
for e in doc.getiterator( 'titletext' ):
    book_title = e.text
```

In general, I've found ElementTree easier to work with than BeautifulSoup, at least for the kinds of things that I work with.  I've found that it's slightly faster for our cases and it handles cases like yours more easily (in my opinion).

HTH.

Comment: Does using the cElementTree make it faster? Started using it after Thomas K pointed it out and it does what I need. The only annoyance i had was that it prepends the namespace on every tag.

Comment: Given that cElementTree is a C version of ElementTree, I'm sure that there are components to that module that are faster than ElementTree itself.  It is almost certainly faster for some operations.  It's hard to know whether it's faster for you or not - probably depends a lot on use case.